# My IE doesn't support "document.getElementById()"!

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

My IE is IE 6. It's pretty old, but I have to use it.

I just found a strange problem, it doesn't support "document.getElementById()"!

See my test file: test.html

```
<a id="aaa">xxx</a>
<script>
aaa = document.getElementById("aaa");
alert(aaa);
</script>
```

When I open this file by IE, there shows an ERROR dialog:

```
line: 3
char: 1
error: object doesn't support the attribute or method
code: 0
URL: file://D:/test.html
```

Do I made some mistakes? It's so strange ~

Comment: Is that your _entire_ test file, or just snippets from it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Its because the anchor element is set up (in IE6) as a global variable with name aaa. And then you are trying to use another variable with same name.

If you change it to...

```
<a id="aaa">xxx</a>
<script>
bbb = document.getElementById("aaa");
alert(bbb);
</script>
```

it should work.

See http://verens.com/2005/03/18/getelementbyid-bug-in-ie6/

Comment: I don't observe any difference in behavior between his code and yours using IE6 on XP.

Comment: @meder, of course I did.  I ran both sets of code locally, and there's no behavior difference on my machine.  If it's just my machine, then fine.  And from the upvotes I gather that it is.  I wasn't accusing him of being wrong, just stating that fact; no need to accuse me of not reading.

Comment: thank you!! Yes, you are right~~ If you don't tell me this, I will never know. I must spend several hours or days to debug this problem. I love stackoverflow, and love you all!

Answer (score 4):

Change the variable name so that its not the same as the element id.

Answer (score 4):

As noted by barrylloyd,  its because the anchor element is set up (in IE6) as a global variable with name aaa. You can use var to create a local variable called aaa:

```
<a id="aaa">xxx</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
var aaa = document.getElementById("aaa");
alert(aaa);
</script>
```

Comment: You and barry have got to the answer but the terminology needs a little finessing. The variable you create above __is__ a global variable not a local variable.  What IE does is a little trick that if a search up the scope chain for an identifier fails even at the global level __then__ it searches its index of element ids, if it finds a match it returns it.  This is not something other engines do and its really annoying the IE does it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a snippet of your html file or the entire file? In the first case I'd suggest adding the appropriate tags (`<html>`, `<body>`), and a doctype. Second, the element should be loaded when you execute this javascript, but with IE6, I would not rely on it. Therefore you might want to try it inside an onload function:

```
window.onLoad = function() {
  alert(document.getElementById("aaa"));
}
```

Comment: it's the entire file. I add tags as you said, but the problem is still there. And, @barrylloyd is correct. But thank you all the same

Answer (score -3):

It works if you place the javascript block within the `<head>` tag section.  There's where JS should normally be placed anyway.

Comment: That's not true, and performance-wise not recommended: http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2007/07/high_performanc_5.html

Comment: Hm, interesting point about moving scripts to the bottom to speed up rendering.